# Problems insert node at specific position in linkedlist

Tags: c, list, insert, position, nodes

I have some problems with the function insertnodespecific. When I run this program, I first use the insertNodeFirst() function, and then I use the insertNodeEnd() function. Then I run the list listNode() function, and all's well. However, when I try to use the insertNodeSpecific function, and either the node gets added as the last on in the linked list, or it's added in another position. Can anyone see something wrong with the function? I assumed the function would look something similar to the insertNodeEnd() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct node {
   int data;
   int key;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
void insertNodeFirst();
void insertNodeEnd();
void insertNodeSpecific();
void listNode();

int choice = 0;


int main()
{

    while(true)
    {
    printf("Enter a choice:\n"
    "1: Insert a node at the beginning of the list:\n"
    "2: Insert a node at the end of the list:\n"
    "3: Insert a node at a specific position in the list:\n"
    "4: List nodes: \n"
    "5: Exit: \n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                insertNodeFirst();
                break;

            case 2:
                insertNodeEnd();
                break;

            case 3:
                insertNodeSpecific();
                break;

            case 4:
                listNode();
                break;

            case 5:
                exit(0);
                return 0;

            default:
               printf("Invalid choice! \n");
               break;
    }
}
    return 0;
}




void insertNodeFirst()
{
    int data;
    int key;
    printf("Type in a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    struct node *link = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    link->key = key;
    link->data = data;

    link->next = head;      // point to old first node
    head = link;            // point to new first node


}




void insertNodeEnd()
{
    int data;

    printf("Type in a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    struct node *newNode, *temp;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        temp = head;
    }

    while(temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newNode; //inserted data

}



void insertNodeSpecific()
{
    int data = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int i;

    printf("Type in a value:  \n");
    scanf("%d", &data);

    printf("Enter a position: \n");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    struct node *temp2, *insertnode;
    insertnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    insertnode->next = NULL;
    temp2 = head;

    insertnode->data = data;


    if(temp2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory! \n");
    }

    while(pos--)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    temp2->next = insertnode;

}


void listNode()
{
    struct node *ptr = head;
    printf("List of nodes are:\n");
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: `temp2->next = insertnode;` Consider what `insertnode->next` points to at that stage and what it should actually point to instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it should point to temp2->data = insertnode? I've tried this now, and the value gets inserted to the correct position, but when I use the listNode function it gives out the wrong value.

Comment: `temp2->data = insertnode`? That's obviously not correct and won't even compile. `data` is an `int` whilst `insertnode` is a `struct node *`.

Comment: Thank you, you made me realize that I don't really understand pointers. temp2->data = data; should be correct.

Comment: I don't think that's correct either. That will overwrite the original data value. It means it will *replace* not *insert*. Is that really what you want? I doubt it as you call `malloc` to create a new node. To insert it should be more like: `insertnode->next = temp->next; temp->next = insertnode;`